# Wordpress my query post doesn't display my post with category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I am new to wordpress, I have a post that has a category_name of offer and it has a content, here is the permalink : `http://localhost/jcjohn/2016/09/20/what-we-offer/`

Now I want to display the contents of my post from my section page.

Here is my code inside the section :

```
<section id = "offer">
<?php    
    $args = array(
        'type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'category_name' => 'offer',
    );
    $offerBlog = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($offerBlog->have_post()):
        while ($offerBlog->have_posts()):
            $offerBlog->the_post();
            get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); 
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();    
?>
</section>
```

Comment: change 'type' into 'post_type' in $args variable.

Comment: @vrajesh thank you for your answer sir . still no output sir. please help

Comment: try : replace get_template_part() function into the_content(); @jc John ..note that you  have added posts in "post_type" as 'post'..

Comment: nothing sir ;'(

Comment: @JcJohn. Provided with an Syntax. Try and let me know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what you would need to do to display the post on the single page. You seem to have missed the `s` from `have_post` so it needs to be like below

**Note:** This would go inside `index.php`

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'category_name' => 'offer',
);
$offerBlog = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<!-- Blog Article -->
<section id="blog">
    <?php
    if ( $offerBlog->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $offerBlog->have_posts() ) : $offerBlog->the_post();

        the_content();

        endwhile;
    else : ?>
        <div class="no-content">
            <h3>Well... it looks like we forgot to put content here.</h3>
        </div>
    <?php
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You try using this loop with the `cat_id` that you have for the category you create.

```
query_posts( array( 'cat' => '1', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
```

You can have a try of the replaced code as follows.

```
<section id = "offer">
<?php    
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'cat' => '1',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'orderby' => 'title', 
        'order' => 'DESC' 
    );
    $offerBlog = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($offerBlog->have_posts()):
        while ($offerBlog->have_posts()):
            $offerBlog->the_post();
            get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); 
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();    
?>
</section>
```

You have missed the loops format.

**Reference:**

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Kuhmar.P Thank you for your answer sir, where should i put that sir ? sorry i'm just a beginner, can i put it in my $args?

Comment: Just place `'cat' => '1', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'DESC'` in $args by removing your old $args.

Comment: $args = array (
       'post_type' => 'post',
       'cat' => '1',
       'posts_per_page' => 5,
       'orderby' => 'title',
       'order' => 'DESC'
      );
still nothing sir .. :(
http://localhost/jcjohn/2016/09/20/what-we-offer/?preview_id=36&preview_nonce=9ca15bc6d7&post_format=standard&preview=true